# How do I make my calculator work in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, calculator, pysimplegui

Im trying to make a calculator work in PySimpleGUI but I cant understand how to make it actually calculate. This is the code I currently have.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
sg.theme('DarkAmber')
layout = [[sg.Button('7', key = '7'), sg.Button('8', key = '8'), sg.Button('9', key = '9'),],
          [sg.Button('4', key = '4'), sg.Button('5', key = '5'), sg.Button('6', key = '6'), sg.Button('+', key = '+')],
          [sg.Button('1', key = '1'), sg.Button('2', key = '2'), sg.Button('3', key = '3'), sg.Button('=', key = '=')]]

window = sg.Window('Calculatrice', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    num1 = ''
    num2 = ''
    
    if event == event: 
        if event == '+':
            if event == event:
                    num2 = str(num2) + event

        num1 = str(num1) + event
        
        if event == '=':
            print(num1 + num2)

        
window.close()
```

So far, I've tried a few variations of the current code but this it the best layout I've found and the code looks like it should work but doesnt.

Comment: `if event == event:` will always be true, so this conditional is redundant

Answer (score 0):

Set the initial settings, the do the related actions for each event during the event loop.

Example Code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkAmber')
layout = [
    [sg.Text('', size=0, expand_x=True, background_color='green', key='Display')],
    [sg.Button('7', key = '7'), sg.Button('8', key = '8'), sg.Button('9', key = '9'),],
    [sg.Button('4', key = '4'), sg.Button('5', key = '5'), sg.Button('6', key = '6'), sg.Button('+', key = '+')],
    [sg.Button('1', key = '1'), sg.Button('2', key = '2'), sg.Button('3', key = '3'), sg.Button('=', key = '=')],
]
window = sg.Window('Calculatrice', layout)
n1 = True
num1, num2 = 0, 0
while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event in "0123456789":
        if n1:
            num1 = num1 * 10 + int(event)
            window['Display'].update(f'{num1}')
        else:
            num2 = num2 * 10 + int(event)
            window['Display'].update(f'{num1} + {num2}')
    elif event == '+' and n1:
        n1 = False
        window['Display'].update(f'{num1} +')
    elif event == '=':
        result = num1 + num2
        window['Display'].update(f'{num1} + {num2} = {result}')
        n1, num1, num2 = True, 0, 0

window.close()
```

[image]